PrimeOS 2.1.0 rpi 4b dsi display dont work
Good morning.
I have a dsi touch screen thats works with all distros android on my rpi 4b, but dont work with PrimeOS 2.1.0.
The rainbow appears but after, don't show anything.
All distros android start via usb.
including PrimeOS 2.1.0 start in usb ( with hdmi cable connected to tv), but not in dsi display, same if i disconetc hdmi cable.

Try booting in different modes (like safe mode) to see if the DSI display works:

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Tentei em modo de segurança, e nada.

Sou novo por cá.
E estou a utilizar o smartphone para fazer as perguntas.
Já consegui resolver uma parte do problema que é vizualizar no ecrã touch 7 polegadas .
Mas há outro problema.
É que ao modificar o config.txt ele entra e consigo trabalhar com o PrimeOS 2.1.0 mas se reenicio já não dá porque o config.txt volta ao original, para conseguir entrar tenho sempre que configurar o ficheiro ( config.txt ).
Porque isto acontece?
Como posso definitivamente resolver este problema?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Config.txt sempre que reenicia volta ao original .

Parece que ninguem sabe porque . Vou disistir do rpi e vou para outra plataforma.

I edited the config.txt, added the command.
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-dsi-7inch.
This on windows.
I removed the card and put it in rpi 4b, nothing happened.
I removed the card, put it in the PC and the command disappeared.
I reinserted the command, removed the card, reinserted it into the PC to check that it was recorded (yes it was) I inserted it back into the rpi 4b and again (nothing). I removed it from the rpi and put it on the PC.
The command disappeared again.
What do I do?

this is not an answer to the question ... please delete it ... update your question instead
